# Changing the background image of linux mint boot screen

Tags: linux, grub, splash

I suppose the boot manager for linux is called grub, how do I change the splash image for it?

Update:

the methods mentioned don't quite do what I want. This grub is customized for linux mint it seems, (or something like that). It uses a graphical menu, this line in `/boot/grub/menu.lst` is responsible for that.

```
## Graphical boot menu location
gfxmenu=/boot/gfxmenu/linuxmint.message
```

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://www.arsgeek.com/2006/08/21/how-to-give-yourself-a-grub-splash-screen-of-your-choice/) gives details on how to set it up. A **summary**:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick  # if you don't already have it
cd /boot/grub
sudo mkdir images
sudo cp menu.lst menu.lst.bak  # make a backup just in case
cd images
cp /path/to/image.jpg .
sudo convert -resize 640x480 -colors 14 image.jpg splashimage.xpm
sudo gzip splashimage.xpm
```

Now to tell grub to use that image...

```
sudo gedit ../menu.lst  # or your favorite editor
```

Add the following line below the initial comments:

```
splashimage (hd0,1)/boot/grub/images/splashimage.xpm.gz
```

**Note**: the `(hd0,1)` might be different for you, check the list of kernels in `menu.lst` to see what it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

If using the command line is not your thing, you can use a tool called "Start-up manager", which simplifies things.

[image: screenshot of the Start-up manager]

It can be used to change lots of options, including the Grub background image.

The tool can be found via aptitude (Debian distribs), more info can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090309160906/http://web.telia.com/~u88005282/sum/installation.html).

(Be careful changing boot options, as it could render your system unbootable.)